# Cannot edit the launch screen in main storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

I'm very new to XCode and swift. I created a launch image in the launch story board. But, I wanted a customized delay for the launch screen. So, I copy pasted the UIViewController from launch storyboard to the main storyboard and connected it to the first page of my app (which is a table) with a modal segue, created a swift file, connected the UIViewController to the corresponding class and customized the delay for the launch screen. 
However the image in the launch screen is not aligned when I run the app. When I edit the picture in the main storyboard, I see no change when I run the app. I realized that I had to make the changes in the launch storyboard. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the class of the View Controller in your launch storyboard file (using the Identity Inspector. You are not allowed to have custom classnames in launch screens. Also, consider posting some code or pictures so that other's can help you. @A.G.

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. You have two storyboards. You need to edit both of them if you want to make a change in the launch/initial view controller